# NAs produced when calling simulate with GLMM fitted with Gamma dist. and log link

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, mixed-models

I'm trying to do a simulation-based power analysis for a GLLM, like the one described [here](http://rpubs.com/bbolker/11703).

My model object is fitted with glmer using a Gamma distribution with log link:

```
fit.gamma = glmer(time ~ display + root + technique + order + (1|user), data=Static, family = Gamma(link="log"))
```

The simulation of the responses works well when I supply the fitted model object:

```
simulate(fit.gamma, nsim=1, newdata=expdat)
```

Result looks good:

```
    sim_1
1     1.8300779
2    12.8543403
3    30.7541107
4     8.2714460
5   162.2040545
```

But I get a warning and wrong output when, instead, I inform the model formula and the parameters of the model:

```
newparams <- list(beta = fixef(fit.gamma), theta = getME(fit.gamma, "theta"),
    sigma = getME(fit.gamma, "sigma"))
simulate(~ display + root + technique + order + (1|user), 
      nsim=1, 
      family=Gamma(link="log"), 
      newdata=expdat, 
      newparams=newparams, 
      allow.new.levels=T)
```

I get the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In rgamma(nsim * length(ftd), shape = shape, rate = shape/ftd) :
NAs produced
```

And the response vector looks like this:

```
    sim_1
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     NaN
```

The problem can be reproduced with the following code:

```
dd   <- data.frame(x=rep(seq(-2,2,length=15),10),  f=factor(rep(1:10,each=15))); 
dd$y <- simulate(~x+(1|f), family=Gamma(link="log"), seed=101, newdata=dd, newparams=list(beta = c(0,2), theta = 1, sigma = 1))[[1]]
```

Working with the formula would be better cause I would then be able to manipulate the parameters to simulate various effect sizes.

The function simulate is supposed to work with either model object or formula. Am I missing something? Is there an argument that I'm failing to pass to the function?

Comment: this might be a bug.  Can we please have a reproducible example?

Comment: this is definitely a bug. Can you submit an issue to https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/ ?

Comment: Yes. I'm working on the reproducible example right now.

Comment: You could use `dd <- data.frame(x=rep(seq(-2,2,length=15),10), f=factor(rep(1:10,each=15)));
    dd$y <- simulate(~x+(1|f), family=Gamma(link="log"), seed=101, newdata=dd, newparams=list(beta = c(0,2), theta = 1, sigma = 1))[[1]]`